# Shell script syntax error for valid file

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, centos

Anyone out here to help with shell script ?
I have shell script in folder /home/username/down/devel (Script file name is php)
When I run the script I get error as follows:-

```
/usr/local/lib/php.ini]: No such file or directory
devel/php: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `"/usr/local/bin/php",'
devel/php: line 4: `exec("/usr/local/bin/php", *args)'
```

But the same sciprt is working at other friends machine. What can be wrong here? Any one here to help on shell script?
Below is my shell script code

```
#!/bin/bash

args=['-c', "/usr/local/lib/php.ini"]
exec("/usr/local/bin/php", *args)
```

Just to mention my php.ini file exists. My machine is linux CentOS release 5.5 (64bit)

Comment: That is certainly not a `bash` script. I don't know what it is, but it looks more like a `csh` script. What happens if you execute the script with `csh pathname/to/script`?

Comment: I get 
args=[-c,: Command not found.

Comment: Looks a lot like python to me.

Comment: That's not [Python's exec statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec), though.

Comment: I'm sorry for. Its ruby and my friend changed its "#!/bin/bash" while sending me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use arrays in bash, take a look at http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/